# Basic question about the Discerete Fourier Transfrom

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have trouble understanding the transition from the infinite integral of the Fourier transform
$$
\mathcal{F}f(v) = \int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{ivk}f(k)dk
$$
to the discrete version 
$$
\mathbf{F}f_n = \sum^{N-1}_{k=0} f_k e^{ink/N}.
$$
I first thought that one picks a finite subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$ and paritions it into $N$ pieces, and then somehow use periodicity of the integrand to extend this to infinity, but $e^{ivk}f(k)$ isn't necessarily periodic. This also doesn't make any sense if I want to calculate the transform for a single value $v$. So what does this finite sum actually represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what might be confusing for you is the fact that there are two different discrete transforms:

1. the [Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), which is only applicable to series with finite lengths (the length is usually denoted by $N$, as in the formula you gave)
2. the [Discrete-time Fourier transform (DTFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform), which is defined for series with infinite lengths:

$$X(\omega)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]e^{-in\omega}$$

The importance of the DFT lies in the fact that there are very efficient algorithms (the [Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fft) algorithm) for its computation.

Answer (score 0):

Try approximating the integral using a Riemann sum, using $N$ intervals of length $1/\sqrt N$, going from $x=-\sqrt N/2$ to $x=\sqrt N/2$.